# Define PHP variable value from Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I need to pass the value of a variable in jQuery to the value of a variable in PHP.

I'm using wordpress and already have AJAX operational.

### Example

### Jquery

var pie = 12;

Then pass the value of pie to.

--

### php

```
<?php $new_pie = <b>value from var pie in jquery needs to go here.</b> ?>
```

hope that makes sense.
thanks guys.

EDIT

Thanks OhGodWhy

That looks like it.

Having a bit of trouble getting it to work though.

Working in wordpress..

jQuery

```
var pie = 'test';

$.ajax({
   url: 'http://localhost:8888/ph/wp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
   type: 'POST',
   action: 'MyAjaxFunction',  
  data: { pie : pie },
  success: function (data){
     console.log(data);
  }
});
```

FUNCTIONS.php

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_my_ajax_function', 'MyAjaxFunction' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_ajax_function', 'MyAjaxFunction' );

function my_ajax_function() {
$new_pie = isset($_POST['pie']) ? $_POST['pie'] : false;
echo($new_pie);
}
```

Comment: If you have 'AJAX operational', then what seems to be stopping you from sending your data?

Comment: I don't know how to do it.. New to AJAX and jQuery.
I can send the value to a div, or a hidden field, but not to a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send the data to the server using jQuery's AJAX.

```
$.ajax({
   url: '/path/to/my/script.ext',
   type: 'POST',
   data: { pie : pie },
   success: function (data){
       console.log(data);
   }
});
```

Use a ternary operator to assign to the variable. Later in your script you can check `if($new_pie)` and if it returns true, the value has been posted, otherwise it was never posted and you can perform whatever logic necessary at that point.

```
$new_pie = isset($_POST['pie']) ? $_POST['pie'] : false;
```

**Edit**

- Based on the above Code, this is Wordpress, and you're not creating your action hook properly. Allow me to address this.

The "action" paramter you supply in your ajax call is actually part of the `data` object. It also must match exactly whatever comes after `wp_ajax_` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_` in your `add_action` argument, see below for proper implementation.

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ajaxurl, //super global supplied by Wordpress; do not change
    type: 'POST',
    data: { 
        action: 'get_post_title', //this is correct
        pie : pie 
    },
    success: function (data){
        console.log(data);
    }
```

});

Now your `add_action` will actually pass along the AJAX request made because `get_post_title` is passed properly as the action from your AJAX request.

Furthermore, the 2nd argument to `add_action` is the literal function name and must not be any different than the function declaration, please see below:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_post_title', 'my_ajax_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_post_title', 'my_ajax_function' );

function my_ajax_function() {
    $new_pie = isset($_POST['pie']) ? $_POST['pie'] : false;
    echo($new_pie);
}
```

Please note how `, 'my_ajax_function` in your `add_action` matches exactly the function declaration of `function my_ajax_function(){`.

This will resolve your issue.

Comment: @DeanMGordon See the Edits brah.

Comment: You are amazing! I have been battling this for a week! Two last things, I can get it to appear in the console using echo in functions.php, but it has a 0 appended to it? Also, How can I echo it so it appears on my page? @Ohgodwhy

Comment: @DeanMGordon Sorry, I left that part out. By default you need to `die();` after you `echo` back your content from an `ajax request`. Otherwise, you will always get a 0 appended to it always.

Comment: Also....about getting it to appear in your page. That's jQuery syntax you'll have to use `$('#elementId').append(data);` will append the data to an element with the ID of `elementID`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `jQuery.ajax()` to send your jQuery data to your PHP script.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/